# Assembler MUL и DIV

Tags: ассемблер

Здравствуйте, изучаю ассемблер, разобрался уже кое-как с регистрами, хранением данных в памяти, понял как происходит складывание и вычитание, но не могу понять, как происходит умножение и деление...
К примеру:
add ax, bx - тут все понятно два операнда, результат поместится в регистр АХ
mul dx - не могу понять, как это работает, где берется второй операнд и куда поместится результат

Answer (score 2):

Команда mul берет первый аргумент из AL/AX/EAX, умножает его на операнд и результат помещает в AX/DX:AX/EDX:EAX в зависимости от размера чисел.

div - аналогично. Делится AX/DX:AX/EDX:EAX на операнд, результат помещается в AL:AH/AX:DX/EAX:EDX (частное:остаток).

PS. Но вообще, это все описано в интеловском справочнике по инструкциям...